# How to construct pair of items on two lists using recursion in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Hie, I am a newbie in Prolog, especially recursion in Prolog. Here, start recursive on list X, makepairs recursive on list Y. These two rules should make a list of the pairs of items on X and Y. For example, if I enter query:

```
?- start([a,b], [c,d], Z)
```

Prolog should print out:

```
Z = [pair(a,c), pair(a,d), pair(b,c), pair(b,d)].
```

But my code prints only `false`. Could anyone help to find the bug in my code?

```
start([H|T], Y, Z):- makepairs(H, Y, Z), start(T, Y, Z).
start([], _Y, []).

makepairs(X, [H|T], Z) :- append([pair(X,H)], [], Z), makepairs(X, T, Z).      
makepairs(_X, [], _Z).
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `library(lamdba)` preinstalled in Scryer, available for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl)|[SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/lambda/prolog/lambda.pl).

```
start(Xs, Ys, XYs) :-
   maplist(\X^Y^pair(X,Y)^true, Xs, Ys, XYs).
```

Or manually,

```
list_list_pairs([], [], []).
list_list_pairs([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [pair(X,Y)|Pairs]) :-
   list_list_pairs(Xs, Ys, Pairs).
```

Note that this not only constructs such pairs, but it can also be used to "unzip" them:

```
?- list_list_pairs(Xs, Ys, [pair(1,one), pair(2,two), pair(3,three)]).
   Xs = [1,2,3], Ys = [one,two,three].
```

But, maybe I should add, using `pair/2` as a functor is fairly uncommon. It is more idiomatic in Prolog to use `(-)/2` instead, which is so much more compact, think of

```
   Ps = [1-one,2-two,3-three].
% vs
   Ps = [pair(1,one), pair(2,two), pair(3,three)]
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for. They want a cross product, not a zip.

Comment: Thanks for using `\X^Y^...`, I knew it existed but I think this is the first time I have seen it in the wild.

Comment: @GuyCoder: [Further sightings in the wild](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+library+lambda)

Comment: @false It like some things that you never really notice until they are pointed out to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a learning exercise, you are supposed to roll your own...

For the purposes of this exercise, I'm going to elect to represent the tuple using the `:/2` operator (`x:y`), simply because it's less typing, more compact, and and easier on the eyes than, say, `[x,y]`.

So, there are 3 cases in this problem:

- Both lists are the empty list. The result is the empty list. You can represent that as

  ```
  zip( [] , [] , [] ) .
  ```
- Both lists are non-empty lists. The result is that we prepend the pair to the result list, and continue, thus:

  ```
  zip( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X:Y|Zs] ) :- zip(Xs,Ys,Zs) .
  ```
- And then, there is the case where one list is empty and the other is non-empty. You need to consider how to handle that situation. You could

  - Fail.
  - Terminate the program and succeed, discarding the unmatched items.
  - Include the unpaired item as itself.
  - Include the unpaired item in the same `x:y` pair structure, selecting some atom to represent the missing data.

  Here, I choose to include the last option, and will represent the missing data with the atom `nil`, so `[nil:y]` or `[x:nil]`.

  You can represent this in Prolog as

  ```
  zip( []     , [Y|Ys] , [nil:Y|Zs] ) :- zip([],Ys,Zs) .
  zip( [X|Xs] , []     , [X:nil|Zs] ) :- zip(Xs,[],Zs) .
  ```

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
zip( []     , []     , []         ) .
zip( []     , [Y|Ys] , [nil:Y|Zs] ) :- zip([],Ys,Zs) .
zip( [X|Xs] , []     , [X:nil|Zs] ) :- zip(Xs,[],Zs) .
zip( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X:Y|Zs]   ) :- zip(Xs,Ys,Zs) .
```

which you can fiddle with at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/zip/unzip.pl

Running

```
zip( [a,b,c], [1,2,3], Ps ).
```

results in

```
P = [ a:1, b:2, c:3 ]
```

You might note that this will also unzip a list of tuples, so running

```
zip(Xs,Ys,[a:1,b:2,c:3]).
```

results in

```
Xs = [a,b,c]
Ys = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for. They want a cross product, not a zip.

Answer (score 0):

This line cannot succeed:

```
start([H|T],Y,Z):- makepairs(H,Y,Z), start(T,Y,Z).
```

The first part requires Prolog to find a value for `Z` which is the list of all pairs, the second part requires `Z` to become only the list of H paired with every element in Y, and the third part requires `Z` to become the pairs of the tail and Y.

One single `Z` cannot be three different things at the same time, the predicate cannot hold, and `false` must be the result.

This line:

```
start([],_Y,[]).
```

Introduces a helper variable, which you never use.

This line:

```
makepairs(X,[H|T],Z):-append([pair(X,H)],[], Z), makepairs(X,T,Z).
```

requires that `Z` is the list of pairs of `X` with everything in `[H|T]`, and also that `Z` is what you get when you append an empty list onto a list with one pair, and that `Z` is the list of pairs of `X` with `T`. This has the same problem of requiring `Z` to be three different things. These lines are where you need to introduce helper variables such as `Z_`.

Answer (score 0):

**Flaws in the predicate `makepairs/3`**

- In the base case, `makepairs(_X, [], _Z)`, the variable `_Z` remains free, but it should be instantiated to `[]`.
- In the recursive case, `append([pair(X, H), [], Z]` is equivalent to `Z = [pair(X, H)]` (however, all you need is `Z = pair(X,H)`); also, the recursive call must produce a list containing the remaining pairs, say `Zs`. So the final result should be `[Z|Zs]`.

Thus, a correct code is:

```
makepairs(_X, [], []).
makepairs(X, [H|T], [Z|Zs]):-
    Z = pair(X,H),
    makepairs(X, T, Zs).
```

Example:

```
?- makepairs(a, [c,d], Pairs).
Pairs = [pair(a, c), pair(a, d)] ;
false. % <= spurious choice point!
```

**Flaws in predicate `start/3`**

- In the recursive case, subgoal `makepairs(H, Y, Z)` produces a list `Z` containing only pairs whose first elements are equal to `H`; then, the recursive call must produce a list `Zs` containing the remaining pairs. So, the final result, say `Zss`, must be the concatenation of lists `Z` and `Zs`.

Thus, a correct code is:

```
start([], _Y, []).
start([H|T], Y, Zss):-
    makepairs(H, Y, Z),
    append(Z, Zs, Zss),
    start(T, Y, Zs).
```

Example:

```
?- start([a,b], [c,d], Z).
Z = [pair(a, c), pair(a, d), pair(b, c), pair(b, d)] ;
false. % <= spurious choice point
```

**A BETTER SOLUTION**

A better solution, that avoid spurious choice point using **first argument indexing**, is:

```
make_pairs([], _, []).
make_pairs([X|Xs], Y, Pairs):-
    make_pairs_helper(Y, X, Px),
    append(Px, Pxs, Pairs),
    make_pairs(Xs, Y, Pxs).

make_pairs_helper([], _, []).
make_pairs_helper([Y|Ys], X, [pair(X,Y)|Zs]):- 
    make_pairs_helper(Ys, X, Zs).
```

Example:

```
?- make_pairs([a,b], [c,d], Pairs).
Pairs = [pair(a, c), pair(a, d), pair(b, c), pair(b, d)].
```

**Remark** It's more idiomatic to use `-` as separator of the elements of a pair in Prolog.